# No Java runtime present, requesting install on R

Tags: java, r

I am trying to run the "H2O" package on RStudio. The code I am using is as follows.

```
 h2o.init(
nthreads = -1,
max_mem_size = "2G")
```

While running this I get the error:

No Java runtime present, requesting install.

```
Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................ 
[1] "127.0.0.1"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 54321: Connection refused"
Error in h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "2g", ip = "127.0.0.1",  : 
  H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''/usr/bin/java' -version 2>&1' had status 1
```

I also get this as soon as I hit run [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWAQw.png). The first time I clicked 'more info' downloaded and installed java. Now I have a java .dmg and .tar file installed yet I keep getting these errors.
Seeing an earlier answer on this forum I also tried the code

```
h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = '2g', 
         ip = "127.0.0.1", 
         port = 54321)
```

But all in vain. Can someone please guide me what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Hello, everyone. I guess previously java was not installed properly. I re-downloaded the JDK and this time it is running successfully. Thank you for your time and apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Elin I am using macOS Mojave. Thanking you for taking time out to look into the problem and try to help me out. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: So the bad news is that getting R + Java to play nicely on MacOS is really hard.  There are a number of blog posts and github threads about it.Sadly I have never gotten it to work 100%.  Usually people suggest using a container instead.

Comment: Well, somehow for me it is working now. I'll keep my fingers crossed!